# Debugging Spark Code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a small spark code here that connects to a RabbitMQ server. However, I keep getting connection refused when I try to run the code. I've checked the ports, server, firewall by creating a separate python script to pull from the RabbitMQ server on the same machine. The python script works but the spark code does not.

I'm wondering how I can debug this exception to get more information about why the connection is being refused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The original code is:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client._
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.RabbitMQUtils
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
import java.net.Socket
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.{InputDStream, ReceiverInputDStream}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver._
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging


object CustomReceiverUT {
        def main(args: Array[String]) {


                //RabbitMQ things
                val host = "1.2.3.4"
                val port = "5672"
                val queueName = "Test_Wave"
                val vHost = "/"
                val userName = "mhadmin"
                val password = "password"


                //Configure Spark properties
                val sparkConfig = new SparkConf()
                  .setAppName("Spark-Stream-Test")
                  .setIfMissing("spark.master", "local[*]")

                val ssc =  new StreamingContext(sparkConfig, Seconds(5))

                val receiverStream = RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, Map(
                        "host" -> host,
                        "port" -> port,
                        "queueName" -> queueName,
                        "vHost" -> vHost,
                        "userName" -> userName,
                        "password" -> password
                ))

                val totalEvents = ssc.sparkContext.longAccumulator("My Accumulator")

                receiverStream.start()
                println("started receiverStream")

                 receiverStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
                      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                        val count = rdd.count()
                           // Do something with this message
                                println(s"EVENTS COUNT : \t $count")
                                totalEvents.add(count)
                          //rdd.collect().sortBy(event => event.toInt).foreach(event => print(s"$event, "))
                   } else println("RDD is empty")
                                println(s"TOTAL EVENTS : \t $totalEvents")
                })


                ssc.start()
                ssc.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

The output is:

```
 17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Starting receiver 0
    17/06/27 16:04:47 ERROR RabbitMQReceiver: Could not connect
    17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver 0 onStart
    17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Waiting for receiver to be stopped
    17/06/27 16:04:47 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Could not connect
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:60)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:911)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:870)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:692)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.org$apache$spark$streaming$rabbitmq$consumer$Consumer$$addConnection(Consumer.scala:269)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$$anonfun$1.apply(Consumer.scala:251)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$$anonfun$1.apply(Consumer.scala:251)
            at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
            at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.getChannel(Consumer.scala:251)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.apply(Consumer.scala:207)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver$$anonfun$3.apply(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:60)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver$$anonfun$3.apply(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:59)
            at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver.onStart(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:59)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:597)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:587)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1976)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1976)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopping receiver with message: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Could not connect: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO RabbitMQReceiver: Closed all RabbitMQ connections
    17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStop
    17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Deregistering receiver 0
    17/06/27 16:04:47 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Could not connect - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:60)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:911)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:870)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:692)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.org$apache$spark$streaming$rabbitmq$consumer$Consumer$$addConnection(Consumer.scala:269)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$$anonfun$1.apply(Consumer.scala:251)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$$anonfun$1.apply(Consumer.scala:251)
            at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
            at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.getChannel(Consumer.scala:251)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.apply(Consumer.scala:207)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver$$anonfun$3.apply(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:60)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver$$anonfun$3.apply(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:59)
            at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver.onStart(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:59)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:597)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:587)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1976)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1976)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like Wireshark to see what is going on over the network? Seems like its a refused socket connection ie networking error.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.ConfigParameters` for available map key names.

```
val receiverStream = RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, Map(
                        "hosts" -> (host + ":" + port),
                        "queueName" -> queueName,
                        "vHost" -> vHost,
                        "userName" -> userName,
                        "password" -> password
                ))
```